# Interception with Autofac for .NET 3.5 SP1

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, autofac, interception

Is there any support for interception with Autofac for .NET 3.5 SP1?

The last version of autofac for .NET 3.5 SP1 is 2.6.3.862.

This is a refresh of the internals of a legacy app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. After we updated to Autofac 3.0 we switched to portable class library format, which doesn't work with .NET 3.5. You should remain on your Autofac 2.6.x version.

Comment: I manage to do this for .NET 3.5 SP1 by using Reflector to disassemble the AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy assembly and recompiling it for .NET 3.5. Interception works like a charm. I wrote Unit Tests to check it all out.

Answer (score -1):

I disassembled AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy and compiled the code for .NET 3.5

Comment: Hard to make sense of this, use [the source](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/contrib/Source/?name=issue-264) Luke.